# C++ map: expected initializer before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error in a header file:

> error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token

```
class MyEntity;
typedef std::map<uint16,MyEntity*> myList_t;
```

I figured it's not seeing the map include, but at the top of that header file is:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
```

In another header file:

```
typedef unsigned int               uint32;
```

Any ideas?

g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

Comment: Are you sure this is the right line? Can you post a complete example that reproduces the error?

Comment: could you please tell us, which compiler you are using, and on which platform? Thx

Comment: This code compiles for me, if I put the line "typedef short uint16;" in front of it.  Where is your uint16 type defined at?

Comment: Are you sure `uint16` is a type? The standard types are called `uint16_t` etc.

Comment: Could it be if I have a map.h and map.cpp that'll conflict?

Comment: @Zeno: There should be no conflict.  `<map>` is distinct from `<map.h>`, and the data-type itself (`map`) is inside the `std` namespace.

Comment: Try to provide a minimal complete example that still has this error. Chances are you'll find the bug yourself and if not, we'll be in a better position to help.

Comment: @Zeno: In your example is says `uint32` in the typedef, and `uint16` in the declaration of the `map`. Is that a typo?

Comment: There could be a macro somewhere causing problems. You might want to check the preprocessor output (`g++ -E`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a macro named map that was causing a conflict.

Comment: This is why macros need to be ALL UPPERCASE.

Comment: It was. `#define _MAP_H` Once I changed that to BMAP and the map files too, it was fixed.

Comment: You should use `MAP_H` instead of `_MAP_H`. An identifier starting with an underscore followed by another underscore or a capital letter is reserved for the C compiler and/or library.

Answer (score -1):

In your actual code (not your simplified example) you are probably missing a `;` from the end of the line before the `typedef`.  This is usually what it means when I get that kind of cryptic error and I can almost reproduce your message by putting another underminated `typedef` above it:

```
q.cc:8: error: expected initializer before 'typedef'
```

My first guess was that `class MyEntity` was a full definition (not a forward declaration) and was missing the `;` but I get a slightly different error for that.

Comment: That *almost*, but not quite the same error-message, and the difference is significant here.

Comment: The error message will depend on what's on the line above, which I suspect is not reproduced in the question.

Comment: In this case, if the line above has a semicolon missing or something of the likes, the error will always be caused by the keyword `typedef`. The compiler will get get to the `<`, as indicated by the error-message of the OP.

Comment: Every map use in this file gets the same error, the rest of the code doesn't have any weird errors.